# "select" is not working if I use in ng-switch directive

Tags: angularjs

select is not working in ng-switch. If I take it out from ng-switch then it show selItems value.

Here is the case in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kulwinder156/2827vLLe)

```
<div ng:app>
<div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
      <div ng-switch on="controlType"> 
            <div ng-switch-when="kendoDropDownList">
                <select ng-model="selItems" ng-options="value for value in zoneList">Select Zone</select>
            </div>
     </div>
          {{selItems}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the ng-switch generate an isolate scope for every when they have.

A possible solution is use the $parent in the model of the select:

```
<div ng:app>
    <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
        <div ng-switch on="controlType"> 
            <div ng-switch-when="kendoDropDownList">
                <select ng-model="$parent.selItems" ng-options="value for value in zoneList">Select Zone</select>
            </div>
            {{selItems}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2827vLLe/1/

Comment: Thank you! I understand the scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-switch-when` creates an isolated scope and the `selItems` value is only available in that scope. Two solutions for this:

**1. Use `$parent`**

```
<select ng-model="$parent.selItems" ng-options="value for value in zoneList">
```

This tells Angular, to add `selItems` to the parent scope (Ctrl-Scope)

**2. Use `controller as` syntax**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

```
function Ctrl($scope)
{
    this.controlType = "kendoDropDownList";
    this.zoneList = ['rr','rrs','dsa'];

}

<div ng-controller='Ctrl as c'>
      <div ng-switch on="c.controlType"> 
            <div ng-switch-when="kendoDropDownList">
                <select ng-model="c.selItems" ng-options="value for value in c.zoneList">Select Zone</select>
            </div>
     </div>
     {{ selItems }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddel link.This is working fine now.

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/2827vLLe/6/
```

Comment: No it's not. If you edit a jsfiddle don't forget to click update to save the changes (generate a new link). And for a good answer you have to put the solution here and the link can be a reference.